# How-Do I Repair a Dual-boot (Windows 8.1) from Elementary OS Freya? GRUB has been restored, but Windows will not boot

Tags: dual-boot

I had a blinking-cursor black screen freeze on my dual-boot Freya/Windows 8.1 system.

I have restored the grub and can recover my Windows files. How can I restore Windows 8.1 to healthy dual-boot with GRUB in charge?

Here is the Boot Issues file: [Boot-Repair BootInfo summary](http://paste2.org/CawB5V2E)
Working through "Boot-Repair" utility: [BootInfo](http://paste2.org/FndWwIkH)

Thanks.

Comment: Resolved just now by running "Boot-Repair" tool! (Installed from Software Centre). Great little app to know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `sudo update-grub` in terminal after booting into elementary. This should detect your Windows 8.1 partition and automatically add it to grub.

Comment: Thanks...I had done all that. Resolved just now by running Boot-Repair utility! Great little app to know about.

Comment: Yes. Real nifty on both platforms-Windows and Linux.